# Unable to Queue a Message using "Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" when Queue status was set to"ReceiveDisabled"

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

Getting below error when try to queue a message

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: ServiceBusOutput. Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus: Messaging entity 'sb://******/QueueName' is currently disabled
```

I'm able to queue message to the same queue using BrokeredMessage from WindowsAzure.ServiceBus library.

How can we queue a message when the queue is in "ReceiveDisabled" status? Thank you.

Comment: The WindowsAzure.ServiceBus package is the older one and might not adhere to same rules as the newer package. Use the newer package.

Comment: It looks like the error you're getting is correct if the queue is disabled. The Management Fluent API might be able to tell you the status of the queue. A heavy overhead if you were to check before every message send but you could check the status on a background thread periodically depending on your use-case.

Comment: @RobMcCabe - thank you for your reply. But the queue is not in **Disabled** state.  It is in **ReceiveDisabled**.  as per this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/entity-suspend' link, **ReceivedDisabled** is partially disabled and it should receive messages but not release. So the new library should allow me to queue right? Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Ah ok, so according to this you can send to the queue but cant receive from it. But it looks like (from your exception message above) that this doesnt seem to be the case - can you verify both sending and receiving are disabled? (You could reenable to send, then set it back to receive disabled to see if you can receive from it again).

Comment: yes, I tried those scenarios using **Service Bus Explorer** and it is working as expected with all 4 states (active,disable,receivedisable and senddisable) and that open-source tool is using **WindowsAzure.ServiceBus**. So new library (microsoft.azure.servicebus) is not working like old one

Comment: The latest version of Service Bus Explorer is 4.1.112, uses a package called Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll, which seems to be using version 4 of Microsoft.Azure.Servicebus. See here:
https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/blob/develop/src/ServiceBus/ServiceBus.csproj suggesting they are using the newer SDK.  This version supports queues with status Active, Disabled, SendDisabled and ReceiveDisabled.  My recommendation is to use the new packages and stick with that! :-) happy coding!

Comment: @RobMcCabe - I tried with 4 version also but no luck. Service Bus Explorer has that 4 version reference for management functionality not for queue logic.

Answer (score 1):

this may be because of the connection string which you are using has access only to send.

Please check in your Azure portal under Shared access key whether your service bus connection string has access to send and receive

[image]

Comment: @kannagokul - my service bus connection is already with "Manage", "Send" and "Listen" enabled